# WaitHandle.WaitAny blocks for multiple seconds despite timeout of 200ms

Tags: c#, deadlock, waithandle

In my program, I am facing some blocks for multiple seconds, which are leading to infrequent timeouts. I added some debug outputs and was now able to identify one responsible line of code:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}: Before WaitAny");
int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(mySyncEvents, 200, false);
Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff}: After WaitAny");
```

A small portion of the debug output shows:

```
02:42:29.636: Before WaitAny
02:42:29.841: After WaitAny
02:42:29.850: Before ExecuteScan
02:42:29.862: After ExecuteScan
02:42:29.863: Before WaitAny
02:42:43.520: After WaitAny       -> very long delay?
02:42:43.546: Before ExecuteScan
```

The question is now what could be the cause for this long delay of nearly 14 seconds despite the short timeout of 200ms? (In theory, also the first Debug.WriteLine may cause the delay, but I have not modified the Debug.Listeners collection.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. I am not able to actually reproduce the issue (the program runs for several hours until the error occurs randomly). The program is a "MachineServer" for a larger application, controlling some hardware devices. I cannot simply take away some parts of the code - and I doubt that I would be able to reduce the issue when starting from the scratch...

Comment: Windows isn't a real-time OS; if the thread performing the wait gets put on the back burner or there is a shortage of thread pool threads there may be an arbitrary delay between the wait completing and the thread continuing, although admittedly 14 seconds is extreme. The "hardware devices" might also be interfering if this is custom hardware and the device drivers are not designed to play nice with user mode.

Comment: What are the `mySyncEvents` anyway

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think you are correct. Maybe I am overinterpreting my finding and actually the (whole?) application blocks randomly. If this occurs, the thread will most of the time be waiting in the WaitAny method (the code of the loop itself runs very short). I will check this assumption by putting some logs in other threads like this one. Hopefully, I can track down the root cause. Thank you!